# Published App 3 days go, not showing in market/play, is it a Proguard.cfg issue?

Tags: google-play

I created an Android app and published it in the Android market about 3 days ago.

The app is reported as published in my developer dashboard but it is now showing up. When I was exporting the signed APK with eclipse I had an error in my Proguard.cfg file. I couldn't find a solution so I deleted the file and compiled the app and uploaded it to the android market.

Could the deleting of the Proguard.cfg file have impacted my apps visibility in the android market? Any tips on what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proguard.cfg is used when building the release build of the app, but is optional.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

So this is unlikely to be the problem.

I would check your developer console on the market place, and see if you have published the app, or activated the apk correctly.